# ViewHolder from Adapter from Fragment starts Activity, how can the Activity talk back to the Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

`PlaylistFragment` starts an adapter:

```
playlistsAdapter = new PlaylistRecyclerAdapter(playlistsListArray, addToPlaylist, mSong, getActivity(), this);
```

`PlaylistRecyclerAdapter` binds data to the `PlaylistViewHolder`, something like this:

```
((PlaylistViewHolder) viewHolder).bind(this, dataSet.get(position), addToPlaylist, mSong);
```

User clicks on an item in `PlaylistViewHolder`:

```
context.startActivity(PublicPlaylistActivity.createStartIntent(context, playlist));
```

Now here is the question, how can `PublicPlaylistActivity` talk back to the initial `PlaylistFragment`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you'd better use **Interface** from fragment to adapter. So when user clicks anything in adapter, call function realization in fragment. If you need your activity to proceed some operation - **((YourActivity) getActivity()).someMethod()** should be called from fragment.

**Second trick** is using broadcastreceiver to send events. A bit more complicated. You have to launch broadcast in view you need to recive message and send these messages from adapter. This approach is more complexible to debug and support if system is wide spread, so you'd better use interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a common "context" class (ComContext) with an interface. When you create your fragment, you also create this class. And from the activity you can check if it exists or not.

I assume that you already have a helper(AppHelper) class with static variables.

```
public class AppHelper {
   public static ComContext comContext = null;
}

public class MainFragment {

   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

      ConContext comContext = new ComContext();
      comContext.listener = this;
      AppHelper.comContext = comContext;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDataChanged() {

   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroyView() {
       super.onDestroyView();
       AppHelper.comContext = null;
   }

}

public class MainActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      if (AppHelper.comContext != null) {
         AppHelper.comContext.listener.onDataChanged();
      }
   }
}

public class ComContext {
   public interface HelperListener {
      void onDataChanged();
   }

   public HelperListener listener = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing that. The simplest way should be starting the `PublicPlaylistActivity` with `startActivityForResult`. In that way, then the activity finishes, you can set send some data to the caller fragment (which is `PlaylistFragment` in your case). Here is a [nice tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en) about the implementation.

Another way of doing that is by using lifecycle methods. You might have a `public static` variable which can keep track of some status that you might observe in your `onResume` function of your `PlaylistFragment` when you are returning back from your `PublicPlaylistActivity`. You might consider a sample implementation as follows.

Define a `public static` variable in your `PlaylistFragment`. Then in your `onResume` function check the value of that variable and take actions accordingly.

```
public static boolean someIndicator = false; // Initialize with a default value

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(someIndicator == true) doSomething();
    else doSomethingElse();
}
```

Now you can set the indicator variable from anywhere in your application actually which will have the effect on your `PlaylistFragment`. For example, from your `PublicPlaylistActivity`, you might consider doing something like this.

```
public void someFunctionInYourPublicPlaylistActivity() {
    // ... 
    // Some code and then the following
    PlaylistFragment.someIndicator = true;
}
```

Another way of achieving the same thing is by using a `BroadcastReceiver`. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) on how you can implement one.

It really depends on how you are structuring your whole activity-fragments communication. Hope that helps!